# PHP OOP Problem

Tags: php, oop

This is my parent class:

```
class Model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $table, $idField='id';
    public $fields;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fields  = new ValFieldGroup();
    }
    //Other Code
}
```

Here's the code of the ValFieldGroup class:

```
class ValFieldGroup
{
    private $fields = array();

    public function add($name, $rules = '', $label = '')
    {
        $this->fields[$name] = new ValField($name, $rules, $label);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->fields[$name]))
            return $this->fields[$name];
        else
            return false;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->fields[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }
}
```

Here's the child class where I'm getting an error:

```
class User extends Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields.add('first', 'required', 'First Name');
        // Snip
    }
    // Snip
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I run this code:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add() in \models\user.php..
```

Which is this line in the class `User`:

```
$this->fields.add('first', 'required', 'First Name');
```

When I do a `print_r($this->fields)` before this line, I get:

```
ValFieldGroup Object ( [fields:private] => Array ( ) )
```

So clearly the class is being setup but I can't use the function I want.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fields.add` is not valid syntax in PHP - if you have a property named `$fields`, it'd have to be `$this->fields->add`

Comment: @Peka - Actually, it's valid syntax by pure chance. It concatenates the `$this->fields` property with the output of function `add()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless `add` is a function from the global scope, I'd say `fields.add()` should be `fields->add()`. The dot is the string concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: I tend use periods as member operator all the time xD

Answer (score 2):

Your User class extends SuperModel, not Model.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling the method correctly, try this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields->add('first', 'required', 'First Name');
        // Snip
    }
    // Snip
}
```